# How to convert "12:45pm - 01:00pm Today, September 7" into UTC

Tags: python

I have the following time string

```
12:45pm - 01:00pm Today, September 7
```

and I want to convert this string into UTC datetime in the following format

```
2016-09-07T22:45:00Z
```

How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Let me search the package for you ... https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime/4.0.1

Comment: sorry I forgot to attach code. that. Will note it down. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
developed the script to achieve it.

    def appointment_time_string(time_str):
        import datetime
        a = time_str.split()[0]

        in_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%I:%M%p')

        start_time = str(datetime.datetime.strftime(in_time, "%H:%M:%S")) + "Z"

        if time_str.split()[3] == 'Today,':
            start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT")
        elif time_str.split()[3] == 'Tomorrow,':
            today = datetime.date.today( )
            start_date = (today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT")

        appointment_time = str(start_date) + str(start_time)

        return appointment_time
```